# Are those 2 linq equivalent?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following linq statement :

```
_champs.Where(a => a.NoPage == noPage + 1).Any()
```

and

```
_champs.Any(a => a.NoPage == noPage + 1)
```

in an if condition.

The first one look easier to read for me and seem more logic than the second but both work just fine.

Is there any reason to use more #1 than #2 or vice and versa?

edit : I will stick to the second one since it seem a bit better than first one. It's easy to read also and sound more natural... actually I found the second one more often in my code (after a quick look up)

Comment: Using `2` is more convenient, concise and of course we should use it. BTW, I find the second a little **easier** to read than the first.

Comment: Technically `2` could potentially be a bit faster, as `1` requires an instance of `WhereEnumerableIterator` to be created. I don't believe you'd be able to observe the difference though.

Comment: I once stumbled upon the following error: `_champs.Select(a => a.NoPage == noPage + 1).Any()`. Because of the connotations of the phrase "Select", it is easy to miss the fact that this does not work as intended! The full explanation is left as an easy exercise for the audience. I advice for the concise version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes both of them are **equal**.

> Is there any reason to use more #1 than #2 or vice and versa?

For clarity, the second version with `Any` is clear, IMO. Since it displays the intent that the code is looking for existence of `Any` instance.

Answer (score 1):

They are **equivalent but not equal**

They will return the same result but the compiler generates different IL. (It won't be optimized even in Release mode.)

For this code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var _champs = new List<Champ>();
            var noPage = 0;
            var q = _champs.Where(a => a.NoPage == noPage + 1).Any();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

And for this one:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var _champs = new List<Champ>();
            var noPage = 0;
            var q = _champs.Any(a => a.NoPage == noPage + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

While this is actually not a problem for LinqToOjects, and for many ORMs like EntityFramework it will generate only one call to database, keep in mind that it is technically possible that some unoptimized ORM could generate two calls to database since there are two method calls, although I haven't looked or found any.

**Always prefer the second one since it's safer than the first.**

Answer (score 0):

They are equal and will high-probably be optimized to the same expression tree.

Comment: If this is plain Linq-to-Objects, i.e. works on `Enumerable` with delegate `Func<ChampType, bool>`, there are no expression trees. In that case it won't be optimized to the same thing. His first version is less direct than his second one.

Comment: That's why "probably" :)